# Rails 4.0.5 secret.yml configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration-files

So I'm trying to get my first ruby on rails app running and after running "rails s" for the first time, I get the following message when I navigate to localhost:3000:

> Internal Server Error
>
> You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.

I did some research and it looks like I need to configure my secrets.yml file but am unsure what it should look like. This is what my secrets.yml file looks like:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

development:
  secret_key_base: fe3ffe8d0308f92a4765f3ea02264cd24f1ddc9dd5a64aa601c61402c85e2de4d5fb74df8d66ef6d2a43dee34584dce87a51f83050d4d1d57320b5e846a6a8aa



test:
  secret_key_base: fe3ffe8d0308f92a4765f3ea02264cd24f1ddc9dd5a64aa601c61402c85e2de4d5fb74df8d66ef6d2a43dee34584dce87a51f83050d4d1d57320b5e846a6a8aa


# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

the development and test secret_key_base come from the key that's generated when I run "rake secret".

What am I supposed to put in the production secret_key_base (that's what I speculate is wrong)?

Edit: What is my config/initializers/secret_token.rb file supposed to look like? This is what I have for that:

Demoapp::Application.config.secret_key_base = fe3ffe8d0308f92a4765f3ea02264cd24f1ddc9dd5a64aa601c61402c85e2de4d5fb74df8d66ef6d2a43dee34584dce87a51f83050d4d1d57320b5e846a6a8aa

SOLUTION: I had forgotten to put the generated key in quotes inside my config/initializers/secret_token.rb file. config/initializers/secret_token.rb now looks like this and works fine:

Demoapp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'fe3ffe8d0308f92a4765f3ea02264cd24f1ddc9dd5a64aa601c61402c85e2de4d5fb74df8d66ef6d2a43dee34584dce87a51f83050d4d1d57320b5e846a6a8aa'

Comment: The config/initializers/secret_token.rb file should be removed and the key from that should be put into your production server's SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable, as explained by @vee. The point of this change in Rails 4.1 was to centralize all "secret" data into a singular file (secrets.yml) and get prod secrets out of the code base.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to add an environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` with value from a new `rake secret` command on the server that hosts this production environment.  In `secrets.yml`, the production `secret_key_base` is assigned the value of this environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

Please see [Environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable%22) for information on the subject across different platforms.

Setting the environment variable satisfies the requirement, and you need not modify the `secrets.yml` file.